# Duplicate message problem in MS Access VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Still new to coding in MS Access.  Need some assistance.

What I want to be able to do is capture a person in my table multiple based off the request date however if the request is the same date I want my message for duplicate record to show.  Right now my code is looking at first name and last name only and if I enter the same person in on my form with a different date it thinks its a duplicate.  Need to fix this.  below is my code.  I want to add something in this to look at the date as well as the names.  The field for the date is Date_of_DMIPasswordReset

```
 Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    If DCount("*", "Tbl_DMIPasswordResets", "FirstName = '" & Me.txtFirstName & "' AND LastName = '" & 
    Me.txtLastName & "'") > 0 Then
        If MsgBox(Me.txtFirstName & " " & Me.txtLastName & " Is already in the DMI Password Reset table 
    to be approved" & vbNewLine & _
            "Do You want to Delete this record", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate Entry") = vbYes Then
                Me.Undo
        End If
    Else
        Form_BeforeUpdate (0)
        If blnSaveRecord Then
            Me.Dirty = False
            MsgBox "DMI Password Reset for this Employee Saved", vbInformation
            Me.cboEmpLookup.Requery
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Add date criteria into the DCount() expression.

Comment: Also try names containing quotes (like O'Connor), then read [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)!

Comment: Thank you --your response were a big help